# How to create CultureInfo instance using the full name or convert the full name to CultureInfo code?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to create an instance of cultureInfo object using the full displayname:

```
CultureInfo userCulture = new CultureInfo("Japanese (Japan)");
```

or convert the full displayname to culture code:

```
toCultureCode("Japanese (Japan)");
```

would return  `"ja-JP"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no builtin method to get a culture by it's english name, so you could write one:

```
public static CultureInfo getCultureByEnglishName(String englishName)
{
    // create an array of CultureInfo to hold all the cultures found, 
    // these include the users local culture, and all the
    // cultures installed with the .Net Framework
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
    // get culture by it's english name 
    var culture = cultures.FirstOrDefault(c => 
        c.EnglishName.Equals(englishName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    return culture;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/2DK70n)

The `toCultureCode` is `ToString`:

```
String name = "Japanese (Japan)";
CultureInfo japanCulture = getCultureByEnglishName(name);
Console.Write(japanCulture.ToString()); // -> "ja-JP"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq

```
using System.Linq;

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).FirstOrDefault(c => c.DisplayName == "Japanese (Japan)");
```